# protractor unable to set the ng-model value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Im using materialize css for the date-picker and using protractor to test it as shown in 
http://plnkr.co/edit/pSskRfOy3f1NKo6KYgWD?p=preview

When i tried to  `element(by.model('newPatReports.reportDate')).sendKeys('14 January, 2016');` Im unable to set value instead open up the date-picker- this happens on firefox only

But in chrome it says cannot focus element...What could be the possible way to bind with my model

I also tried to remove the custom attribute, but i didnot succeed

Any help is appriciated.......Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to remove the `readonly` attribute from the date `input` element, click it to trigger the date picker, hide the date picker and send keys to the `input`:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
    rptdate = element(by.name("rptdate"));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(rptdate), 15000);

// remove the "readonly" attribute
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly');", rptdate.getWebElement());

// trigger the date picker
rptdate.click();

// hide the date picker
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';", $('.picker').getWebElement()).then(function () {
    rptdate.sendKeys('14-12-2015');
});
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks buddy.........but now input doesn't have 14-12-2015......its not yet binding it..

Comment: @AmoghAngadi interesting, worked for me for the plunker you've provided. the `.picker` element is the actual date picker that we are hiding so that it would not be overlapping the input.